# dataframe row level operation error when append the new calculated value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like
[image]
in the CSV.

I want to get
[image]

I have received error:

```
 91             return converter(self.iloc[0])
     92         raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to "
---> 93                         "{0}".format(str(converter)))
     94 
     95     wrapper.__name__ = "__{name}__".format(name=converter.__name__)
```

TypeError: cannot convert the series to

Following is my code

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
a=data['a']
b=data['b']
value=sqrt(a**2+b**2)

data['value']=value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1

One way is to use list comprehension:

```
value=[math.sqrt(x**2+y**2) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Full code example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import math

data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
a=data['a']
b=data['b']
value=[math.sqrt(x**2+y**2) for x,y in zip(a,b)] 

data['value']=value
```

### Method 2

Or use `numpy` here to do the element wise operation.

```
import numpy as np
...
np.sqrt(..)
```

So this code works as expected

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
a=data['a']
b=data['b']
value=np.sqrt(a**2+b**2)

data['value']=value
```

Adds a column with designated value which is element wise square sum of first 2 columns.

Comment: @NewPy.: Yes...exactly. It can not work as you expected it to be. But you can have nice workaround by using `map` or `list comprehension` etc

Answer (score 0):

Since the `sqrt` is not an inbuilt function like `sum()` in python, you need to use packages like `Numpy` or `Math` to call the `sqrt` function.

```
import numpy as np
np.sqrt(a**2+b**2)
```

or

```
import math
math.sqrt(a**2+b**2)
```